# Where does Magento 2 Generate Image URLs

Tags: magento2, php, frontend, apache

I recently switched a Magento 2 system from serving public files out of

```
/path/to/magento
```

to serving files out of

```
/path/to/magento/pub
```

i.e. I wanted Apache to use the `index.php` file in the `pub` folder.  However, Magento is still generating image and asset URLs with `pub` in the URL

```
http://magento.example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

instead of

```
http://magento.example.com/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

This is happening for images, javascript, and css file.

The obvious question: Why is this happening, how can I fix it.

The less obvious question: Where does the PHP logic reside for adding `pub` to asset URL so I can debug this myself.

Cache had been cleared with a

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the caches weren't entirely cleared.  The system was running with the default full page caching enabled, and I had failed to clear the `var/page_cache` folder.